# How to send data to a php file and load it as a current page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send JSON of the selected exam to take_exam.php page via POST so the take_exam.php can display the test for the student.

exams.php file has a list of exams. A student can select an exam to take it. I am currently sending a JSON of {action:"get_exam", exam: "exam_name" } to the take_exam.php so it can display the exam for the student.

JavaScript code to send post data to take_exam.php

```
    var btns =document.getElementsByClassName("stu-take-test")
    for (var i =0; i < btns.length; i++){
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var obj = new Object;
            obj.action = "get_exam";
            obj.exam = this.id;

            str_json = JSON.stringify(obj);

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    location.replace("take_exam.php")

                }

            };

            xhttp.open("POST", "take_exam.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send(str_json);
        });

    }
```

PHP code of **take_exam.php** to grab the JSON sent via ajax, just for testing I am trying to print the JSON received. In future the file would communicate with databse to load the test for the student. But looks like the file is receiving nothing:

```
    <?php

            $real_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $decoded_json = json_decode($real_json);

            print_r($decoded_json);
```

Ajax replaces the exam.php with take_test.php for student to take the selected test

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is nothing happening? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: The page is empty. Try it here: https://web.njit.edu/~yp235/490/frontend/stu_home.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you redirect after success XHR (readyState == 4 and status == 200) to same script without payload. Try to comment `location.replace("take_exam.php")` to see what happens.

But maybe you want check if `$decoded_json` is `stdClass` (it means that json received and decoded) and log result to console:

```
<?php

$real_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded_json = json_decode($real_json);
if($decoded_json instanceof stdClass) {
    // do somethong
    var_dump($decoded_json);
    // and die maybe =)
    die();
}
```

and in JS:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // location.replace("test.php")
    // do something with response
    console.log(this.response);
}
```

**Update**:

Save this in one PHP file (let's say test.php, because `xhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);`) and open in browser.

```
<?php
            $real_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $decoded_json = json_decode($real_json);
            if($decoded_json instanceof stdClass) {
                var_dump($decoded_json);
                die();
            }
?>
<button class="stu-take-test" id="math">Math</button>
<div id="response_container"></div>
<script>
var btns =document.getElementsByClassName("stu-take-test")
    for (var i =0; i < btns.length; i++){
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var obj = new Object;
            obj.action = "get_exam";
            obj.exam = this.id;

            str_json = JSON.stringify(obj);

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('response_container').innerHTML = this.response;
                }

            };

            xhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send(str_json);
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: But how can I reload the page so the user can see the content of the test on take_exam.php so student can take and submit the test?

Comment: You using XHR. It's no needs to reload the page. `this.response` contains response to your request. For example, your page has div with id `container`. Then `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = this.response;`. You need complete example for this?

Comment: I want to send data of the selected test from the list of exam and replace the current page with the take_exam.php where student can take and submit the test. see here: web.njit.edu/~yp235/490/frontend/stu_home.php

Comment: After clicking an exam from the list the page is replaced but it's a blank page

Comment: Not at all, always happy to be of help =) I hope you understand concept =) By the way, if you still need to go to a separate page passing the parameters - then it will be easier to use forms (`<form action="take_exam.php" action="post">...</form>`) and handle params in PHP by `$_POST`. Like this: `<?php $exam = $_POST['exam'] ?? ''; switch($exam) { case 'math': { echo 'Math selected.'; break; } }`